# Different name fields user table?

Tags: authentication, laravel-4

I have a form with 2 fields (**username, password**) and a mysql table with those 2 same fields (username, password), and I authentication system working properly :)

But, I can not make it work if my table fields have different names, for example: (**my_user, my_pass**).

If you just change the **username** field on the other also works for me, that gives me problems is the **password** field.

My config *auth.php*

```
'driver' => 'eloquent'
```

#### Update

Already found the solution in my controller, the `password` name can not change.

Before (WRONG):
What I've done in first place was wrong

```
$userdata = array(
        'my_user' => Input::get('my_user'),
        'my_pass' => Input::get('my_pass')
    );
```

it should be

```
$userdata = array(
        'my_user' => Input::get('my_user'),
        'password' => Input::get('my_pass')
    );
```

Comment: Please post the relevant code and note any frameworks/mapping APIs you may be using.

Comment: Solution for `Eloquent` to be found here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26002552/laravel-4-custom-named-password-column/26002831#26002831

Answer (score 7):

You can define you own username and password field in the `auth.php` inside the config folder.

```
 return array(
    'driver' => 'eloquent',
    'username' => 'my_user',
    'password' => 'my_pass',
    'model' => 'User',
    'table' => 'users',
 );
```

I hope this can be of some help.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this same problem. You need to extend your model:

```
// User.php

use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;

class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

    protected $fillable = array('name','passwd','email','status','timezone','language','notify');
    protected $hidden = array('passwd');

    protected $table = "users_t";
    protected $primaryKey = "uid";

    public static $rules = array(
        'name' => 'required',
        'passwd' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required'
    );

    public function getAuthIdentifier() {
        return $this->getKey();
    }

    public function getAuthPassword() {
        return $this->passwd;
    }

    public function getReminderEmail() {
        return $this->email;
    }

    public static function validate($data) {
        return Validator::make($data,static::$rules);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -4):

You need to implements this methods too:

```
public function getRememberToken(){

}
public function setRememberToken($value){

}
public function getRememberTokenName(){

}
```