# Laravel custom authentication user fields

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I created a table fields with costume fields names `fld_ID, fld_Username, fld_Password` but i can't use this fields type on simple laravel Authentication, so i defined my ID field name on **user model** except laravel-4:

```
protected $primaryKey = 'fld_ID';
```

and for Password name:

```
public function getAuthPassword() {
    return $this->attributes['fld_Password'];
}
```

and finally for my username on Post Action Defined a username type for attempt:

```
$input = Input::all();
$user['fld_Username'] = $input['fld_Username'];
$user['fld_Password'] = $input['fld_Password'];

 if (Auth::attempt($user)){
 ....Some Code Here... :)
 }
```

but still i have problem with and `Auth::attempt` return false, my last Query log is this:

```
Array ( [query] => select * from `tbl_users` where `fld_Username` = ? and `fld_Password` = ? limit 1 [bindings] => Array ( [0] => username [1] => password )
```

and password is Hashed before save.

Comment: idk, but you are missing a closing parenthesis after Auth::attempt to close the if.

Comment: that's not the problem i edited that line, tnx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you changed the password field's name, you need to make a custom user provider and register it in config file.

As you can see in `vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Auth\EloquentUserProvider.php` line 138 the password field is hard coded and there is no other way to change it.

So make a class somewhere is app folder like this:

```
class CustomUserProvider extends EloquentUserProvider
{

    public function retrieveByCredentials(array $credentials)
    {
        if (isset($credentials['fld_Password'])) {
            unset($credentials['fld_Password']);
        }

        return parent::retrieveByCredentials($credentials);
    }

    public function validateCredentials(UserContract $user, array $credentials)
    {
        $plain = $credentials['fld_Password'];
        return $this->hasher->check($plain, $user->getAuthPassword());
    }

}
```

Now you need to introduce this user provider to laravel. just add this to `app\Providers\AuthServiceProvider.php`:

```
class AuthServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
    //...

    public function boot()
    {
       \Auth::provider('CustomUserProvider', function ($app, array $config) {
            return new CustomUserProvider($app['hash'], $config['model']);
        });
    }

    //...
}
```

Just one more step. in `config/auth.php` edit the `providers` section like this:

```
    'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'CustomUserProvider', // make sure you change this
            'model' => CustomUserModel::class, // here is your custom model
        ],
    ],
```

I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

The array you pass to `attempt` is simply an array; it has nothing to do with your database table. you don't have to use `'fld_Username'`, and `'fld_Password'`.  Instead just use `$user['username']` and `$user['password']`.
Laravel is looking for the word "password" as the key in the array you pass to see which is the password.

([Proof](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Auth/EloquentUserProvider.php#L75))

Comment: i shouldn't change them, by the way, there are many developers who want to have a custom field name http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17222734/laravel-4-different-name-fields-user-table-auth, and http://forums.laravel.io/viewtopic.php?pid=49835 and etc...

Comment: Ok, then you need to extend the UserProviderInterface, and swap your implementation with the default EloquentUserProvider.  Don't forget to register your auth driver.  That might seem like killing a fly with a cannon, but you gotta do what you gotta do.  But really, that fly is just a dust particle to most people, if you know what I mean.

Comment: what about this https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Auth/EloquentUserProvider.php#L53-L55 and Guard instances?

Comment: ([See Here for extending Auth](http://laravel.com/docs/extending#authentication)) You are right in that Auth retrieves the user based on the key of your credential array while filtering out password.

Answer (score 0):

Simply override the `username` function from `LoginController` and return your username field, just like this:

```
class LoginController extends Controller
{
    .
    .
    .
    public function username()
    {
        return "fld_Username";
    }
}
```

No need to change anything else except the `getAuthPassword` method that you just did correctly.

I hope this will help you.

Comment: opppps 4 sal pish in soalo porsidi :DDD sry nadidam :)