# Laravel auth different column name for username password

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

Basically, I'm having a problem with laravels built in auth my problem is it only accepts if username is spelled "username" and password "password" but I am using a different spelling username = user_name, password = passwd

this is my code

```
Auth::attempt(array(
    'user_name' => $data['email'],
    'passwd' => $data['password']
));

if( Auth::check() )
{
    return Redirect::intended('/');
}
```

my column name is user_name, passwd

if I use the code above it does not work but if i rename my column to username and password and change my code to this below it works, but unfortunate I am not allowed to do so

```
Auth::attempt(array(
    'user_name' => $data['email'],
    'passwd' => $data['password']
));
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [laravel 4 custom named password column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26002552/laravel-4-custom-named-password-column)

Comment: why don't you change the name of the columns in your table?

Comment: check this http://www.mindworksdev.com/2013/06/laravel-4-different-usernamepasswd-fields-in/

Comment: as stated in my post, renaming my columns is not allowed

Comment: @TheShiftExchange thank you for your comment, now I understand :) 
Is it possible to manually log the users but not using auth::attempt and store it in Auth session?

Comment: @TheShiftExchange I think you are wrong. I've just created solution and it seems to work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26073309/how-to-change-custom-password-field-name-for-laravel-4-and-laravel-5-user-auth/

Comment: @MarcinNabiałek Why did you duplicate the question then post the answer there? You should post the answer here and delete your question

Comment: @TheShiftExchange Because there are many questions about the same and I won't add the same answer in all questions. Moreover I hope that someone more experienced in Laravel will look at it because I'm not 100% sure it won't cause any other problems

Comment: @MarcinNabiałek - your answer looks correct - so post it here and delete your question. Then when other people post the same 'question' that get closed as a duplicate to this question. That is how SO works.

Comment: @TheShiftExchange OP haven't written anything about using `getAuthPassword` in question. I've mentioned about it in my question because I saw it in other places and people told it doesn't work for them

Comment: @TheShiftExchange It's not that `password` field can't be changed. Only problem is `attempt` method, where you can't pass your password with different array index. Only this is hard-coded in the Eloquent provider, but db column may be named as you like.