# How to change / Custom password field name for Laravel 4 and Laravel 5 user authentication

Tags: php, authentication, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5

I would like to change password field in database when using Laravel authentication. I want my column in `users` table has name `passwd` and not `password`. I tried to run something like this:

```
Auth::attempt(array(
    'user_name' => 'admin',
    'passwd' => 'hardpass',
));
```

but it doesn't work.

I also tried to add in `User` model the following function:

```
public function getAuthPassword() {
    return $this->passwd;
}
```

but it also changes nothing. User is still not being authenticated. Is it possible in Laravel to change password field name in database ?

Comment: @JarekTkaczyk It's true, but there is no info there for user who want to have custom password column in database. OP mentioned just using `getAuthPassword` but for user who is looking for solution he still won't know what to do. I thought this Q&A will be helpful for other users to solve this problem step by step

Comment: Just a hint - most of the time the most valuable answers are those short and consise, that precisely address the issue.

Comment: @MarcinNabiałek you saved my life this stupid custom field in my project has been driving me bananas

Answer (score 57, accepted):

## Information

You can change easy all other fields in database and use them for authentication. The only problem is with `password` field.

In fact `password` field is in some way hard coded in Laravel (but not the way many think) so you cannot just pass array as you passed in your question.

By default if you pass array to `attempt` (and probably other Auth functions like `validate` or `once`) if you do it this way:

```
Auth::attempt(array(
    'user_name' => 'admin',
    'password' => 'hardpass',
));
```

default Eloquent driver will run the following query:

```
select * from `users` where `user_name` = 'admin' limit 1;
```

After getting this data from database it will compare password you gave with password property for User object that was created.

But if you simply use:

```
Auth::attempt(array(
    'user_name' => 'admin',
    'passwd' => 'hardpass',
));
```

the following query will be run:

```
select * from `users` where `user_name` = 'admin' and `passwd` = 'hardpass' limit 1;
```

and no user will be found in database (in `passwd` you store hashed password). This is because Eloquent removes from query `password` but use any other data to run query. Also if you try here to use `'passwd' => Hash:make($data['password'])` although user will be found, comparing password won't work.

## Solution

Solution is quite easy. You need to run `Auth::attempt` like this:

```
Auth::attempt(array(
    'user_name' => 'admin',
    'password' => 'hardpass',
));
```

As you see you still pass `password` as key (although this column doesn't exits in `users` table)  because only this way Eloquent driver won't use it for building query.

Now in `User` model (`app/models/User.php`) file you need to add the following function:

```
public function getAuthPassword() {
    return $this->passwd;
}
```

As you see you use here the column that really exists in database: `passwd`.

Using it this way you can have column with password named anything you want and you can still use default Eloquent driver for it.

## Sample data to test

I've created very simple test for it.

You just need to replace your `app/routes.php` file with the following:

```
Route::get('/', function () {

    if (Auth::check()) {
        echo "I'm logged in as " . Auth::user()->user_name . "<br />";
        echo "<a href='/logout'>Log out</a>";
    } else {
        echo "I'm NOT logged in<br />";


        Auth::attempt(array(
            'user_name' => 'admin',
            'password'  => 'hardpass',
        ));


        if (Auth::check()) {
            echo "Now I'm logged in as " . Auth::user()->user_name . "<br />";
            echo "<a href='/logout'>Log out</a>";
        } else {
            echo "I'm still NOT logged in<br />";
        }
    }


});

Route::get('/logout', function () {
    Auth::logout();
    return "You have been logged out";
});


Route::get('/db', function () {

    if (!Schema::hasTable('users')) {


        Schema::create('users', function ($table) {
            $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('user_name', 60)->unique();
            $table->string('passwd', 256);
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });

        DB::table('users')->insert(
            [
                [
                    'user_name' => 'admin',
                    'passwd'    => Hash::make('hardpass'),
                ]
            ]
        );
    }

    echo "Table users has been created";
});
```

1. Create empty database and set connection data in `app/config/database.php`
2. Now you can run `/db` url for example `http://localhost/yourprojectname/db` just to create users table.
3. Now  you can run `/` url for example `http://localhost/yourprojectname/` - as you see user is logged in even if in `users` table in database you don't have any `password` column (data for authentication has been passed as strings without any forms but of course in real application you will add them) . You can run this url once more time  - as you see user is still logged so it is working as expected.
4. If you click on `Log out` link, you will be logged out

## Laravel 5 changes for above

This solution was tested in Larave 4.2.9 (everything as above) and also in Laravel 5. In Laravel5 everything works the same but you need of course edit files in different paths:

1. `User` model is in `app/User.php` file
2. routes are in `app/Http/routes.php` file
3. Database config file is in `config/database.php` file

Comment: thank you very much. I've been struggling with this for a few days.

I was intuitively trying 
Auth::attempt(array(
    'user_name' => 'admin',
    'password' => 'hardpass',
));

Comment: thank you very much. I've been struggling with this for a few days.

I was intuitively trying 
Auth::attempt(array(
    'user_name' => 'admin',
    'member_password' => 'hardpass',
));

the custom password field must be returned in the User model (e.g. app/User.php):


 public function getAuthPassword()
 {
  return $this->member_password;
 }