# Laravel Reset Password Using Different Column Name

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

i managed to make it work when it comes to authorisation with different columns name either username, email or password.

[How to change / Custom password field name for Laravel 4 and Laravel 5 user authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26073309/how-to-change-custom-password-field-name-for-laravel-4-and-laravel-5-user-auth/)

however the password reminder seems doesnt work.

i have changed the user model, to my table column name.

User Model:

```
use Illuminate\Auth\UserTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;

class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

    use UserTrait, RemindableTrait;

    protected $primaryKey = 'user_id';
    protected $table = 'user';

    public function getReminderEmail() {
        return $this->user_email;
    }

    public function getAuthPassword() {
        return $this->user_pwd;
    }

    public function getRememberTokenName() {
        return 'user_token';
    }

}
```

User Controller

```
Auth::attempt(  array(
 'user_name'    => $username, 
 'password'     => $password
), TRUE );
```

Reminder Controller // Error: Column email not found 
(Not sure, its not reading the user model **getReminderEmail()**)

```
public function post_reminder() {

        switch ($response = Password::remind(Input::only('email'))) {

            case Password::INVALID_USER:
                return Redirect::back()->with('error', Lang::get($response));

            case Password::REMINDER_SENT:
                return Redirect::back()->with('status', Lang::get($response));
        }


}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Took me hours to figure it out. Laravel official doesnt seems give a proper documentation to implement the custom name field.

We just need to change the input field name the same with your table column name.

```
Field could be anything
<input type="email" name="user_email">
```

Answer (score 0):

I think we can add custom fields, Here are steps which I figure out to add custom fields.

1 - add `input` field in register view.

```
i.e. <input type="email" name="you_custome_field">
```

2 - open app/services/Registrar.php and register you custom fied in create function.i.e.

```
public function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
            'you_custome_field' => $data['you_custome_field'],
        ]);
    }
```

3 -  (optional) Open `user model` app/User.php register you field as `guarded` or `fillable` as you want.

I hope this will work.