# How to have a different Email column name and in hasOne relation table for password reset Laravel 5.8

Tags: php, laravel

I tried to change default email field for reset password (the email field is in other table that my User model has `hasOne` relation to this table, and field name is `Email` not `email`),
 I override method `getEmailForPasswordReset` in `User` model with field `Email` from `hasOne` relation from another table.
 And now its just refresh the page and nothing happens, its even didn't write reset request with token to `password_resets` table.
If I go with the flow route->controller->method, I'm getting to `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\SendsPasswordResetEmails` to method `sendResetLinkEmail` and here I think this check `$this->validateEmail($request)` doesn't work.
 If I doing `dd` to `$request` before this check I get my request.
 
Below I've added my image of overriding the `getEmailForPasswordReset` method

This is my User model:

```
<?php

namespace App;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

/**
 * Class User
 * @package App
 */
class User extends Authenticatable
{

    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'Allowed_Users', 'Email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    protected $table = 'sometable';

    protected $primaryKey = 'recordId';

    public $timestamps = false;

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
        'Allowed_Users' => 'integer',
    ];

    public function property()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Property', 'id', 'Allowed_Users');
    }

    public function getEmailForPasswordReset()
    {
        $user_property = $this->property()->get();
        return $user_property[0]->Email;
    }
}
```

Thx for help

Comment: Hi Alex, If you'd provide code here we would be able to help you more efficiently :)

Comment: Hi, thx for reply. No problem, just tell which part of code will help and i`ll add it here, User model?

Comment: Yes and avoid pasting code via images.

Comment: @KhalidKhan can you advice to me something or when can i check else?

Comment: Sorry bro, Actually I was very busy, Can you do dd() to your property and check wether you are getting anything there ?

Comment: thisis one of the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27757723/laravel-reset-password-using-different-column-name  which I think will help. Let me know if it helped you or not

Comment: Hi, it didn't help.. And when i try to dd the property in `getEmailForPasswordReset` method its even didn't get here

Comment: @KhalidKhan its giving
`public function validate()
    {
        if ($this->fails()) {
            throw new ValidationException($this);
        }

        return $this->validated();
`
in `Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException`