# Unable to log in when using Laravel Auth

Tags: php, laravel-4

I am trying to follow Solution [given](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26073309/how-to-change-custom-password-field-name-for-laravel-4-and-laravel-5-user-auth/26073310) here.

`getAuthPassword()` returns the correct hash value yet I am not being authenticated. Code snippet given below:

**In Controller**:

```
    public function doLogin()
    {
//        View::composer('layouts.master', function($view)
//        {
//
//            $view->with('login_status');
//        });
        $rules = array(
            'username'    => 'required',
            'password' => 'required'
        );


        // run the validation rules on the inputs from the form
        $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);


        if ($validator->fails())
        {
            return Redirect::to('login')
                ->withErrors($validator)
                ->withInput(Input::except('password'));
        }
        else
        {



            $credentials['username'] = trim(Input::get('username'));
            $credentials['password'] = trim(Input::get('password'));

            //if (Auth::attempt(array($credentials), true))
            if (Auth::attempt($credentials))
            {
                echo 'Success';
            }
            else
            {
                print 'faled';
                dd(DB::getQueryLog());
                exit;
                return Redirect::to('login');

            }

        }
```

**User Model**

```
class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

    use UserTrait, RemindableTrait;

    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'users';

    /**
     * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = array('password', 'remember_token');

    public function getAuthPassword()
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

}
```

**Data in Db**
[image]
if it is running correct password the why is it getting failed?

Comment: Have you checked the values of `Input::get()` to make sure they are correct?

Comment: @TheShiftExchange I guess `getAuthPassword()` returns password after authentication so I guess its right?

Comment: No - that has nothing to do with what I asked. If you do `dd(Input::all());` before you try the Auth - are the values there correct?

Comment: I get user name and plaintext password

Comment: How are you originally hashing the passwords?

Comment: @TheShiftExchange by using HAsh::make()

Comment: Is there anyway I can use some Loggin mechanism to figure out which query is being executed? Something similar to Rails?

Comment: Is the password field in your DB long enough? It should be 60 characters or the hash will be truncated

Comment: @kamlesh.bar Interesting doing this gave another error now `select * from `users` where `0` = adnan`

Comment: @Volatil3 Why are you using `getAuthPassword()` anyways when your column has the default name? (`password`)

Comment: @Volatil3 sorry about that it will require couple more field like remember_token in DB and that's not problem with you. for Auth::attempt you just need to have two fields username and password in DB users

Comment: @lukasgeiter I was just trying to set it explicitly. It did not help either

Comment: @Volatil3 can you please put your database structure above. if you have remember_token field i suggest you add second params attempt to false/true

Comment: @TheShiftExchange Is there ayway I can see query behind it?

Comment: Event::listen('illuminate.query', function($sql)
{
  Log::error($sql);
}); // put this in routes.php file to get query

Comment: @Volatil3 you can access ran queries with `DB::getQueryLog()`

Comment: @lukasgeiter where do I put that?

Comment: @Volatil3 Somewhere after `Auth::attempt()` in this case I'd suggest in the else block. Simply add a line with `dd(DB::getQueryLog())` to get it printed in your browser.

Comment: @lukasgeiter it returned this: `faledarray(1) { [0]=> array(3) { ["query"]=> string(50) "select * from `users` where `username` = ? limit 1" ["bindings"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(6) "adnan" } ["time"]=> float(0.96) } }` It is not checking password field yet getting failed

Comment: It wont check the password in the sql function - it is just trying to match a username first

Comment: Do you have a user in your database `username` with `adnan`?

Comment: @TheShiftExchange Yes and this is why it is returning record in Query in my SQL client

Comment: Your going to have to post your full view, controller, model and a database schema if we are going to work this out. There is something wrong - but its not in the code above

Comment: @TheShiftExchange Question Updated

Comment: Can you also post where you create the user? I.e. where/how you are hashing the password

Comment: @TheShiftExchange Found the issue. I was calling calling `$faker->username` in the loop twice. So by the time `$faker->username` was set in `password` field it was already changed. Thanks for the input. Please make your comment an Answer