# postLogin() override in laravel 5 giving undefined index error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-validation

In my `user` table , coumns name for email is `user_email` and password is `user_pass`

I would like to override `postLogin()` method inside `AuthController` to be able to authenticate the users

Here is what i tried

```
 public function postLogin(\Illuminate\Http\Request $request)
{
        $this->validate($request, ['user_email' => 'required|email', 'user_pass' => 'required']);

        $credentials = $request->only('user_email', 'user_pass');


     if ($this->auth->attempt($credentials, $request->has('remember')))
        {
            return redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath());
        }
}
```

This throws `ErrorException in EloquentUserProvider.php line 111:
Undefined index: password`

But I'm not passing password index at all !! from my login form the name of input is `user_email` and `user_pass`

Any Clue

Comment: Password is hardcoded, see this for a solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26073309/how-to-change-custom-password-field-name-for-laravel-4-and-laravel-5-user-auth

Comment: seems to work, still testing and will post the solution when I'm satisfied ;-)