# Laravel 5 Auth change table column

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I changed some fields in users database table.
table name: users
primaryKey: user_id
username: user_username
password: user_password
e-mail: user_mail

I updated login.blade.php to this:

```
<form method="POST" action="/auth/login">
{!! csrf_field() !!}

<div>
    Username
    <input type="user_username" name="user_username" value="{{ old('user_username') }}">
</div>

<div>
    Password
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password">
</div>

<div>
    <input type="checkbox" name="remember"> Remember Me
</div>

<div>
    <button type="submit">Login</button>
</div>
```

in Illuminate\Foundation\AuthAuthenticatesUsers I added
protected $username = 'user_username';

When i try login to my account when i handed username and password i see blank page.
Debug is on but not working.
What happend?

Comment: If debug is on but now working, you'd better check the error logs. But if you happily changed the password field in the database and didn't tell Laravel, I guess that's the source of the error, and maybe you can find how to fix that here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26073309/how-to-change-custom-password-field-name-for-laravel-4-and-laravel-5-user-auth

Comment: Thanks. My mistake. i moved User class to User\User. I edited auth.php and now it's working. Thanks for helping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have one problem.
I try to log on my account but i can't do this. It's blank page.

```
Auth::attempt(array(
            'user_username' => 'pionas',
            'user_password'  => '12345',
        ));
```

I User model i add **getAuthPassword** and change column name to user_password.
Log is clear...