# Laravel manual authentication: Auth::attempt always false

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

i am using laravel manual authentication system.Submitting the form redirects to this route shown below.And in the authenticate ()  function the name and password never matches to which i stored earlier. i.e. `Auth::attempt` is always false.

```
 Route::post('/logintest', 'mycontroller@authenticate');
    Route::get('/home', ['middleware' => 'auth', function() {
  echo "home page";});
}]);
```

authenticate function:

```
public function authenticate(Request $request)
         {
            $input=$request->all();
            $password=$input['password'];
            $name=$input['name'];

            if (Auth::attempt(['Name' => $name, 'Password' => $password]) ){
            return redirect()->intended('/home');
        }   else 
          {
                return redirect('/login')->with('message','Error logging in!');
            }
        }
```

I've registered the user this way. the password is hashed using bcrypt(). function. but in authenticate() function i am comparing with plain password. i somewhere read `Auth` automatically handles it. OR Is there something should i  change in config/auth.php because i've used name to authenticate instead of username?

```
public function register(Request $request)
{
    $input=$request->all();
    $password=bcrypt($input['password']);
    $name=$input['name'];
    $insert= User::insert(['Name'=>$name,'Password'=>$password]);
    return redirect('/login')
            ->with('message','successfully Registered.');
}
```

Comment: Can you please show us the routes file?

Comment: @VipindasKS i've shown them at top.

Comment: Is this the only routes defined. Just want to make sure that it doesn't conflict with any other routes. Especially, If you had done a php artisan make:auth earlier.

Comment: Can we see you migration file for the user table?

Answer (score 5):

There is a problem with the names. `Auth@attempt` takes all those credentials, except `password` (case sensitive), that you pass in that array and runs a where query (This is how you can add extra constraints to the attempt, as they are just where conditions). If it finds a model it then will do a hash check on the `password` credential (case sensitive) you passed and the model's hashed password which it gets from `$model->getAuthPassword()`.

This field in the credentials is a special one as it is what Auth needs so it knows what field in the credentials is meant to be the password. It does not correlate directly to the field you have used on your `users` table, and must be named `password` in the credentials array. The other fields in the credentials you pass, besides 'password', do correlate directly to the fields on the users table as they are conditions for a database query on that table.

You have to declare in your User model if you are using a field other than 'password' on the table as the password. In your case you are using 'Password'. (this is all case sensitive)

```
class User ....
{
    ...
    public function getAuthPassword()
    {
        return $this->Password; // case sensitive
    }
    ...
}
```

When passing the credentials you pass the plain text password as there will be a `hash_check` happening, not a direct comparison.

You can name the fields what ever you want on your actual table, you just have to make Eloquent aware of this.

Answer (score 4):

Check the code below

```
public function authenticate(Request $request)
{
     $password = $request->input('password');
     $name = $request->input('name');

     if (Auth::attempt(['name' => $name, 'password' => $password]) )
     {
          return redirect()->intended('/home');
     }   
     else 
     {
          return view('login')->withErrors('Error logging in!');
     }
 }
```

Comment: found that the `Auth::attempt` is false because of wrong password. I have used bcrypt() while registering users. `$password=bcrypt($input['password']);` how can i use it here to access?

Comment: $password = Input::get('password');
$hashed = Hash::make($password);

Comment: can you write the code here? i dont know what do you do

Comment: Where is the code? Do you upload the blade and controller file? You said : "i've used name to authenticate instead of username"  --> Can You upload the project or necessary configs and files? Where You save copy of vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers.php file?

Answer (score 2):

You should write Password's p character in small letter.

Replace,

```
Auth::attempt(['Name' => $name, 'Password' => $password])
```

to

```
Auth::attempt(['Name' => $name, 'password' => $password]) // 'p' is in small letter here.
```

check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26073309/how-to-change-custom-password-field-name-for-laravel-4-and-laravel-5-user-auth/26073310) also.

Answer (score 1):

As you're using name instead of email (default) as username to authenticate with. You should add `$username` property inside your `AuthController`.

```
....

class AuthController extends Controller
{


use AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers, ThrottlesLogins;

/**
 * Override the input name 'email'
 * Change it as the name on blade
 *
 * @var string $username
 */
protected $username = 'Name';

....
}
```

Alternatively, you can override `loginUsername()` method from `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers` trait.

```
....

class AuthController extends Controller
{


use AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers, ThrottlesLogins;

/**
 * Get the login username to be used by the controller.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function loginUsername()
{
    return 'Name';
}

....
}
```

Like others said, case matters. You then need to override `getAuthPassword()` method from `Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable` trait on your `User` model

```
....

class User extends Authenticatable
{

....

    /**
     * Get the password for the user.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getAuthPassword()
    {
        return $this->Password;
    }
}
```

Comment: They aren't using the AuthController and if they are they are bypassing all of that as the `attempt` method in their code is hand written.

Answer (score 0):

Everything appears to be correct.

What are the column names in the users table?

Names are case-sensitive. So make sure that they are indeed `Name` and `Password` and not `name` and `password`.

Comment: In `public function authenticate(Request $request)` try changing `$password=$input['password'];` to `$password=bcrypt($input['password']);`

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the command `php artisan make:auth`? It will make everything you need.

Answer (score 0):

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
    Route::post('/logintest', 'mycontroller@authenticate'); 
});
```

1. please check with the above change in your Routes.php, provided you are using version 5 or 5.2
2. Make sure your users table field names are "Name" and "Password" else update it.
3. Check the field length of your `Password` field (in your database, `users` table). It should hold a lengthy, hashed password something like this `$2y$10$eM.kmjTwEIykhNUqMsNzMud0E6eO6RUYAzTqirrbozY1zdhVwQmsC` atleast, (varchar(60))

It would be better if you could show us the users table schema

4. Finally, make sure you are entering the correct password (as I can't see much mistakes in your code)

Comment: can you please show the table structure for 'users' table?

Comment: Yes.  I changed 'Password' to 'password' and it suddenly worked. Thanks for your efforts.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `Name` as unique username and password fiendname as `Password`

You can do this way..

In your AuthController add this method

```
public function loginUsername()
{
    return 'Name';
}
```

And in your User model add this method

```
public function getAuthPassword()
{
    return $this->Password; 
}
```

Hope this will work.

Comment: They aren't using the default AuthController.

Answer (score 0):

Try to switching to lowercase indexes in this line:

```
//...
if (Auth::attempt(['Name' => $name, 'Password' => $password]) ) {
//...
```

To

```
//...
if (Auth::attempt(['name' => $name, 'password' => $password]) ) {
//...
```