# Hash::check() works but Auth::attempt fails (custom User model)

Tags: session, laravel, authentication, login-attempts

I'm learning about Laravel 4, but now I can't login users into my app.
I read multiple tutorials to create a loggin area, but I can't  create a session.

SOLUTION:
[laravel 4 custom named password column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26002552/laravel-4-custom-named-password-column/26002831#26002831)

**You have to be careful with the "password" index, NO MATTER HOW YOUR TABLE NAMES THE PASSWORD FIELD, it must to be "password" in the Auth::attempt function**

The users DB table:

- idusuario, int(11)
- login, varchar(45)
- nombre, varchar(45)
- contrasena, varchar(255)
- status, bool
- remember_token, varchar(100)
- idperfil, int(11)

This is my autentication function:

```php
Route::post('login', function()
{
    if(Auth::attempt([ 'login' => Input::get('login'), 'contrasena' => Input::get('password') ]))
        return Redirect::intended('home');
    return Redirect::to('login')->with('response','Ingreso invalido');
}
```

My custom User Model:

```php
use Illuminate\Auth\UserTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;

class Usuario extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

    protected $table = 'usuario';
    protected $hidden = array('contrasena');
    protected $fillable = array('login', 'nombre', 'status', 'idperfil');
    protected $guarded = array('idusuario', 'contrasena');
    public $primaryKey = 'idusuario';
    public $timestamps = false;

    public function getAuthIdentifier()
    {
        return $this->login;
    }

    public function getAuthPassword()
    {
        return $this->contrasena;
    }

    public function getRememberToken()
    {
        return $this->remember_token;
    }

    public function setRememberToken($value)
    {
        $this->remember_token = $value;
    }

    public function getRememberTokenName()
    {
        return 'remember_token';
    }

    public function getReminderEmail()
    {
        return false;
    }
```

My view:

```php
{{ Form::open(array('url' => 'login', 'role' => 'form')) }}
    <div class="response">{{ $response or '' }}</div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="login">Usuario</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="login" name="login" placeholder="Ingrese su login">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="password">Contraseña</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" placeholder="*********">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Iniciar Sesión</button>
</form>
```

I had been testing with

```php
dd(Auth::attempt([ 'login' => Input::get('login'), 'contrasena' => Input::get('password') ]));
```

But I can't fix it, but when I test the Hash Check to validate the password it returns true!
Some idea to get it?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: duplicate of [laravel 4 custom named password column](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26002831/784588)

Comment: I found and test that post solution before post it, but it doesn't work

Comment: This is it mate, jut make sure you're doing exactly as in linked answer. Otherwise paste the code you tried.

Comment: possible duplicate of [laravel 4 custom named password column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26002552/laravel-4-custom-named-password-column)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I didn't read the 2nd. line of Jarek Tkaczyk's answer in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26002552/laravel-4-custom-named-password-column/26002831#26002831).
Make sure to review your index names if you have the same problem.