# How to change default username/email/password for Authentication on LARAVEL 5?

Tags: php, laravel

I already search for this thing but I'm really new at this and I can't figure it out how to make it work. I'm using a project without many changes so I have my User.php as it comes but I add this:

```
protected $fillable = ['username', 'email', 'password'];//GEN_ID_Usuario

/**
 * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $hidden = ['password', 'remember_token'];

/**
* The eloquent relation to assigment a "formulario" model.
*
*/

public function getAuthPassword()
{
    return $this->Usu_Contrasenia;
}
```

And I have my AuthController as default but I added this:

```
public function authenticate()
{
    $email = $input['email'];
    $password = $input['password']; 
    if (Auth::attempt(array('Usu_Email' => $email, 'Usu_Contrasenia' => 
    $password)))        
    {
        return redirect()->intended('dashboard');
    }
}
```

Everything else in the project it's by default, just trying to use username, email and password as: Usu_Nombre, Usu_Email and Usu_Contrasenia.

Comment: I am not sure if this works for you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26002552/laravel-4-custom-named-password-column/26002831#26002831

Comment: Change `Auth::attempt(array('Usu_Email' => $email, 'Usu_Contrasenia' => 
    $password)` to `Auth::attempt(array('Usu_Email' => $email, 'password' => 
    $password)`. Now `getAuthPassword()` will properly kick in.

Comment: @user2094178 and Hardy Mathew I did what you said and this happend...
QueryException in Connection.php line 624:
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'email' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `Gen_Usuario` where `email` = melis.inf@gmail.com)

Comment: Leave `'Usu_Email'` as it is.

Comment: @user2094178 like this: public function authenticate()
    {
     
     $password = $input['password']; 

  if (Auth::attempt(array('Usu_Email', 'password' => $password)))     
        {
            return redirect()->intended('dashboard');
        }
    } Because I did it this way and still get the error :( I'm so lost.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments exchange, try the following:

```
public function authenticate()
{
    $email = $input['email'];
    $password = $input['password']; 
    if (Auth::attempt(array('Usu_Email' => $email, 'password' => 
    $password)))        
    {
        return redirect()->intended('dashboard');
    }
}
```

Keep in mind the stored password must be properly hashed for `Auth:attemp()` to work as intended.

Comment: Don't forget, you have to update `$fillable` and `$hidden` in your model to reflect the correspondent table schema.

Comment: I did it, I changed the things, except that I don't know about the hashed but I hope I could even register but I couldn't... Got the same error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'email' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `Gen_Usuario` where `email` = melis.inf@gmail.com)... As I said I'm so new at this so I don't have idea :'( But thank you so much for your time.